# Docker tomcat 7 - welcome page access forbidden

Tags: linux, tomcat, tomcat7, docker

I've tried almost everything.

When I go to a docker container by ssh and `curl localhost:8080` there, I get normal welcome page, but If I do `curl host_machine_hostname:8082` from my hostmachine by ssh or from everything else using hostname of my hostmachine, I get error, access forbidden.

I have read alot of suggestions but nothing helped.

Connector settings without address does not help, Valve rules with allow=".*" does not help, Host address=host_machine_hostname" does not help.

**UPD**

I'm sorry. I realized about the root of the problem. I'm using a custom fork of the tomcat and there were specific options for ROOT and other preinstalled packages to block everything while the 127.0.0.1 and the localhost are allowed. So I've got this thing working by removing package-specific context.xml files.

This is because the context.xml in `webapps/{package}/META-INF/` was modified to block everytyhing, and if to Read TFM, package's context.xml has more power above the global context.xml file, that's why I couldn't change anything by modifying the global context.xml.

Comment: If you try to access app inside container from host machine, first of all execute `docker ps` and get container id of the specific image. Then `docker inspect <container_id>`. In the `NetworkingSettings` section you will see `IPAddress` of the container. Then you can use `curl IPAddress:8082` . I assume you exposed 8082 port outside the container.

Comment: You have port 8080 in the first example and 8082 in the second. Is your Tomcat published on both?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL no, it's not working. using container ip from the host terminal is also failing with `access forbidden`. Yes, I've mapped port. 0.0.0.0:8082 -> 8080. I need to make it accessible from outside of host machine, because it's just my work-server, so It have to be accessible from everywhere else.

Comment: @Bryan i'm using tomcat in a docker container. while im inside of container by ssh, i can curl `localhost:8080` and get normal page. while i'm on ssh of host machine (which serves docker containers), i'm unable to get access to tomcat pages and getting `access forbidden` when `curl localhost:8082`. ports differs because I've mapped host port 8082 to the port 8080 inside a container. I made this by setting up docker parameter `-p 8082:8080`

Comment: Which OS is your docker installed> Are you using boot2docker or pure docker on linux? And are you using a public docker image? I can also test it to see problem.

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL i'm sorry guys. I've realized about the root of the problem. I'm using custom fork of tomcat and there were specific options for ROOT and other preinstalled packages to block everything else while 127.0.0.1 and localhost is allowed. So I've got this thing to work by removing context.xml package-specific config files.

Comment: @Flextra could you add your edit as an answer, or close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized about the root of the problem. I'm using a custom fork of the tomcat and there were specific options for ROOT and other preinstalled packages to block everything while the `127.0.0.1` and the `localhost` are allowed. So I've got this thing working by removing package-specific context.xml files.

This is because the context.xml in `webapps/{package}/META-INF/` was modified to block everytyhing, and if to Read TFM, package's context.xml has more power above the global context.xml file, that's why I couldn't change anything by modifying the global context.xml.